# Delete previous snapshots and create new snapshot of EBS volume using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-ebs

I need to create a snapshot of EBS volume using Terraform. I also have to consider that if the EBS volume has previously snapshots or not. If the EBS volume contains some previous snapshots then i need to delete them from my Terraform code and create a new snapshot of EBS volume.

I am not sure if deletion of resources is possible through Terraform code. If it is possible, how can i delete the previous snapshots and create new snapshot of EBS volume with Terraform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not possible. However if the previous snapshots were created by terraform, than running **terraform destroy** before applying the latest version would do the job. But if those snapshots were created by other means than terraform, deleting them using terraform isn't possible at all.